# photo2shape loading error classFactory()

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, photo2shape

Python error: Couldn't load plugin photo2shape due to an error when calling its classFactory() method See message log (Python Error) for more details.

Just updated to the newest version of QGIS and upon trying to use photo2shape when I got this message. Does anyone have an idea s to how to solve the issue?

I'm using version 2.16.2

Comment: Tested, I get "No module named exifread". You'll have to install it in the QGIS python installation to fix the issue. Install procedure depends on your OS and QGIS install.

Comment: Install the new QGIS version or exif into the python directory?

Comment: No dice im afraid. Also tried downloading exifread to the site packages folder to no avail. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There was a [blog](http://quantumofgis.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/qgis-standalone-and-python-modules.html) posted by Werner Macho which describes steps on downloading and installing exifread for Photo2Shape. I just tested this and it works so will post the summary of the steps.

***Note: I am using QGIS 2.16.1 standalone so the paths described will reflect this. Make sure QGIS is not running.***

---

1. Create a new text file and edit it with the following lines:

   ```
   SET PYTHONHOME=C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.16.1\apps\Python27
   SET PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.16.1\apps\Python27\Lib
   SET PATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PYTHONHOME%\Scripts;C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.16.1\bin;%PATH%
   ```

   Save this with the file name "pythonpath.bat" and save it in a folder of your choice (e.g. folder called "folder" on the Desktop).
2. From the Windows "Start" Button, search for `cmd.exe`. Then right-click on it and run it as **Administrator**.
3. Use the `cd` command to go to the folder you created:

   ```
   cd C:\Users\You\Desktop\folder
   ```

   Then type:

   ```
   pythonpath.bat
   ```
4. Now [click here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to download pip to your "Downloads" folder. Then again use the `cd` command to go to the "Downloads" folder:

   ```
   cd C:\Users\You\Downloads
   ```
5. Now we need to call the downloaded script by using DOS names instead of the path names. You can find out what the DOS name of your standalone QGIS directory is by typing:

   ```
   dir "C:\Program Files" /x
   ```

   For me, it mentions `QGIS21~1.1` so now we can type:

   ```
   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\bin\python.exe get-pip.py
   ```

   This will install pip.
6. Once it is finished, we can then install exifread by typing:

   ```
   pip install exifread
   ```

---

And that's it! Load QGIS, from the menubar go to `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...` and check the `Photo2Shape` plugin. Hopefully it is now enabled and ready to go:

[image: Photo2Shape]

[image: Plugin interface]